# C# Can't iterate through string array

Tags: c#

I am trying to iterate through a string array and if it contains a certain string add 1 to an integer but I'm getting an error on the if statement saying:

```
 NUllReferenceException is unhandled
 Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

/

```
 for (int i = 0; i < GlobalData.CellH.Length; i++)
        {
            if (GlobalData.CellH[i].Contains("M"))
            {
                GlobalData.TotalBoys++;
            }
            else if (GlobalData.CellH[i].Contains("F"))
            {
                GlobalData.TotalGirls++;
            }
            else if (GlobalData.CellH[i].Contains(null))
            {
            }
        }
```

**FIXED:**

```
 for (int i = 0; i < GlobalData.CellH.Length; i++)
        {
            if (GlobalData.CellH[i] == "M")
            {
                GlobalData.TotalBoys++;

            }
            else if (GlobalData.CellH[i] == "F")
            {
                GlobalData.TotalGirls++;
            }
            else if (GlobalData.CellH[i] == "")
            {
            }
        }
```

Comment: One or more of your array elements are `null`. Find out why using the debugger. Also, what is `.Contains(null)` supposed to be achieving?

Comment: @LewsTherin - If `GlobalData` or `GlobalData.CellH` where null then the code wouldn't get into the loop at all.

Comment: Ah, I misread.. sorry

Comment: TheOtherGuy, If you are using VS, it has good feature, debugger...

Comment: @LewsTherin, the Wheels of Time apply equally to iteration ;)

Comment: Oh yes, as the first couple of sentences of the first chapter so reminds us ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to perform the null check first, so try this instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < GlobalData.CellH.Length; i++)
    {
        if (GlobalData.CellH[i] == null)
        {
        }
        else if (GlobalData.CellH[i].Contains("M"))
        {
            GlobalData.TotalBoys++;
        }
        else if (GlobalData.CellH[i].Contains("F"))
        {
            GlobalData.TotalGirls++;
        }
    }
```

Also you check for equality with null, as opposed to checking if the string contains null.

Answer (score 4):

Your bottom condition needs to be at the top and modified:

```
for (int i = 0; i < GlobalData.CellH.Length; i++)
{
    if (GlobalData.CellH[i] == null)
    {
        continue;
    }
    else if (GlobalData.CellH[i].Contains("M"))
    {
        GlobalData.TotalBoys++;
    }
    else if (GlobalData.CellH[i].Contains("F"))
    {
        GlobalData.TotalGirls++;
    }
}
```

Also note that this can be done with a few Linq statements:

```
GlobalData.TotalBoys  = GlobalData.CellH.Count(s => s != null && s.Contains("M"));
GlobalData.TotalGirls = GlobalData.CellH.Count(s => s != null && s.Contains("F"));
```

Comment: The LINQ method enumerates CellH multiple times, which could become an issue if CellH contains like... 7billion entries.

Comment: Also you might want to change the assignment to a `+=` since OP might be adding to data obtained elsewhere.

Comment: @WilliamMelani Yes, it could be done with a `.GroupBy` and only iterate once, but as I was writing that I didn't think it saved much complexity.  I gave the Linq examples as more of a illustration than a "best" solution.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether `CellH` is `null`.

Also, `else if (GlobalData.CellH[i].Contains(null))` will cause your exception

Answer (score 0):

This happens if your CellH is null.

Either eliminate the error where you fill your array or avoid it using this code:

```
if (GlobalData.CellH[i] != null)
{
// your code
}
```

Or the better way is using String.IsNullOrEmpty. Then you check for NULL and if it's empty:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(GlobalData.CellH[i])
{
// your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `foreach`, it's there for a reason.

```
// If necessary, first check if GlobalData == null
// and if GlobalData.CellH == null. Then:

foreach (var str in GlobalData.CellH)
{
    if (str == null)
    {
        // ...
    }
    else if (str.Contains("M"))
    {
        GlobalData.TotalBoys++;
    }
    else if (str.Contains("F"))
    {
        GlobalData.TotalGirls++;
    }
}
```

Note that if some array entry contains both letters, only the boys count will be incremented.

Maybe (?!) this is what you mean instead:

```
foreach (var str in GlobalData.CellH)
{
    switch (str)
    {
        case "M":
            GlobalData.TotalBoys++;
            break;

        case "F":
            GlobalData.TotalGirls++;
            break;

        default:    // includes case where str == null
            // ...
            break;
    }
}
```